# Empty (or fill) Recent Apps List

Tags: java, android, locking, homescreen

I have developed a baby app where I need to lock all keys and ways out of the app, in order to be able to hand over the phone to my daughter. I used the "replace home screen" method to capture the home key, and that works great. All other hard keys (except power button, but that's not an issue since it's not easily pressed anyway) are locked. But the often discussed long press of home key is still launching the recent apps and offers a way out (which of course the daughter finds almost instantly).

I have seen other apps in market (toddler lock and more) work around this by emptying the recent apps list (or filling it with an icon that leads back to the baby app), but I have no idea of how to accomplish this. Anyone have a solution? How do I fill the recent apps from my app? Toddler lock even resets the recent apps after the lock-app is exited.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an activity in your application that does nothing, and start it with an intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag set.  <strike>Fire this intent however many times you need to fill the history</strike> (my Incredible has 8 spots).  For repopulating the history, look into ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.getRecentTasks (int maxNum, int flags)
[See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.html)
It looks like you need to hold the GET_TASKS permission

The intents that originally fired those apps are stored as baseIntent, so you should be able to store them yourself(don't forget the extras), and re-fire them in order to repopulate the history list.

This is a hack, but it should work

Edit:  After playing with this a little, it looks like you would need to have  8 different activities for this method to work, which is not realistic.

Comment: I have added three new activities, both in manifest and classes: StartActivity, DummyActivity1, DummyActivity2 and MainAcitivty. I start with the StartActivity, fire dummy1 with flag new task set, then dummy2 from dummy1 and finally main from dummy2. No new icons in the recent apps list when long-pressing home... Do I need to declare the activities in a special way in the manifest?

Comment: I assume all activities are starting.  Do you have:<intent-filter<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />         </intent-filter>  in all of the Manifests?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what is described in Mobius's post, but also set android:taskAffinity="" on the dummy activity elements in the android manifest file.